# Android: Select a part of response json in ApiService by retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-json

I am using Rx,retrofit, dagger with MVP model in android.The response from server is like blow:

```
"User": {
    "Address": "     ",
    "BirthDate": "1395/09/28",
    "ConditionFields": [],
    "CreateDate": "/Date(1482048048370+0330)/",
    "Enabled": true,
    "Export": " ",
    "FirstName": "kia",
    "GUID": "1eaceb23-eace-4cf0-be4d-6d5be338ca46",
    "Groups": [],
    "JobLocation": "2D2722C1-B9AC-4849-AE12-89FCBF6A3A2D",
    "JobLocationName": "",
    "JobLocations": {..},
    ....
```

This was a part of my json response.This response is huge json object. In my api Service, my method return Observable>.This is complete api service :

```
@POST(UrlManager.LOGIN+"CheckOtherUserLogin")
Observable<Response<String>> getUserLogin(
        @Body RequestBody params);
```

When i run my app i got this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

I guess i know what's my problem,this this error is because of the server returned a `json object` but i declare `Response<String>`.

As i said before, the response of the server is huge and must of attribute does not used in my app and i don't want to create **pojo** class with all attributes to store all json information in memory and consume device's memory.So in order to, i want select part of json response exact in api service method.

How could i do that?

Comment: for that you need to create POJO class with a selected field which you want, you are getting an error because of the type mismatch

Comment: @akhilesh0707 but how can i mapped the response to my pojo class in api service?

Comment: goto http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and copy your json generate pojo remove the field which you don't want

Comment: @akhilesh0707 just it? you sure?I am using Gson formatter

Comment: `Observable<Response<String>>` instead of this simply use `Observable<YourPojoClass>`

Comment: @akhilesh0707 I'll try and announce you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167889/discussion-between-akhilesh0707-and-sayres-kabir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create POJO class for the JSON using this link
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

After generating the POJO remove the unwanted fields.

Change your method return type from `Observable<Response<String>>`

```
@POST(UrlManager.LOGIN+"CheckOtherUserLogin")
Observable<Response<String>> getUserLogin(@Body RequestBody params);
```

To `Observable<YourPojo>`

```
@POST(UrlManager.LOGIN+"CheckOtherUserLogin")
Observable<YourPojo> getUserLogin(@Body RequestBody params);
```